# What is the material that goes over Bathroom cupboards to give it a plastic shine look?

Tags: wood

I am assuming it is some sort of laminate but I as the question states I am wondering when the material is that looks like a hard white plastic that goes over wood and tends to be used in bathrooms/kitchens etc. Also is it possible to buy and apply as DIY or is it something that needs to be done in a factory? Thanks

You can see it on the doors in this link

https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/fardal-door-with-hinges-high-gloss-white-s99904189/

Comment: The modern high-loss cabinet stuff is made using more than one type of wrap, vinyl or another resin, over an MDF or particleboard/chipboard core. Regardless of what the surface is I'm pretty sure it's a factory material only. But that doesn't mean you can't get the same look in a DIY solution, there's always painting to consider. Hard work to get a surface close to as good as the plastic wrap, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

A turner in my club does the equivalent of this finish.  In presentations, he's pretty clear that it takes specialized equipment, lots of time and focus for a perfectly level (no orange peel, etc.) shiny (not dull/matte) finish.  He has a special booth, and personal protection so as not to breath fumes.

All in all, I love the finish, but would not undertake such a setup.  There are epoxy finishes that are safer (given plenty of fresh air), and more targeted to one-off types of finishing.  You might try http://www.jamestowndistributors.com/